# Getting issue in SEO Friendly URL in PHP

Tags: php, seo, friendly-url

I am getting issue in .htaccess when I am trying to open any page though seo-friendly URL, then getting "Object Not Found" issue.

Below is my code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)/$ page.php?&page_id=$1
```

What I want

```
http://www.domain.com/about-us
```

But when I am trying to open above URL I'm getting "Object Not Found" issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RewriteRule is looking for "something that ends with `/`".

`http://example.com/about-us` clearly does not end with `/`

So... what did you expect?

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) page.php?page_id=$1
```

Comment: It's working but when i am trying to add "/" behind this url http://example.com/about-us/ then getting issue.

Comment: What kind of issue? Your PHP can just do `rtrim($_GET['page_id'],"/")`